# How to pass field name into update() method of Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I wanna update every field contained in dataToChange object but for some reason I cannot pass key name into update(), I mean that the method does not take it from the outside and it is looking for "key" field in the database's object. How can I do it? I tried to use `${key}`, but it is considered as an error.

```
changeUserInfoFashion = function (id, dataToChange, res, callback) {
       //var id = id;
    _.forIn(dataToChange, function (value, key) {
        key.toString();
        console.log('I AM GOING TO UPDATE ' + key + " WITH " + value);
        User.update(
            {"_id": id},
            //Here I need to pass key -->
            {key: value},
            function (err, results) {
                console.log(results);
                if (err) {
                    return callback();
                }
                return res.json({success: true, msg: key + ' changed.'}).status(200);
            });
    });
 };
```

Examplae of dataToChange is

```
{
name: 'Baby',
age: 32
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to iterate the object and update each field, you can use the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator as follows:

```
changeUserInfoFashion = function (id, dataToChange, res, callback) {       
    User.update(
        { "_id": id },
        { "$set": dataToChange },
        function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            if (err) { return callback(); }
            return res.json({
                success: true, 
                msg: JSON.stringify(dataToChange) + ' changed.'
            }).status(200);
        }
    );    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. Create an empty object and assign key-value to it:

```
_.forIn(dataToChange, function (value, key) {
    key.toString();
    console.log('I AM GOING TO UPDATE ' + key + " WITH " + value);
    var updateData = {};
    updateData[key] = value;
    User.update(
        {"_id": id},
        //Here I need to pass key -->
        updateData,
        function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            if (err) {
                return callback();
            }
            return res.json({success: true, msg: key + ' changed.'}).status(200);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
changeUserInfoFashion = function (id, dataToChange, res, callback) {
       //var id = id;
        User.update(
            {"_id": id},
            dataToChange,
            function (err, results) {
                console.log(results);
                if (err) {
                    return callback();
                }
                return res.json({success: true, msg: key + ' changed.'}).status(200);
            });
 };
```